# How to do this in Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

I want to know how to convert this apache htaccess to nginx.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^url/([^/]+)$ process.php?tk=$1 [L]
```

Is this correct?

```
disable_symlinks off;
rewrite ^url/([^/]+)$ process.php?tk=$1 [L]
```